# Mysql Intermediate Table- Better to Have Repeating rows?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, database-normalization

In a database, I have a username table and I have jurisdiction table. I also have intermediate table to assign a user to one or more jurisdictions.

```
user table
--------------
userID
first_name
jurID

jurisdiction table
-----------------
jurId
region

user_jurisdiction
------------------
userID 
jurID
```

This would lead to something like:

```
 user_jurisdiction
    +--------+-------+
    | userID | jurID |
    +--------+-------+
    |      6 |     2 |
    |      6 |     3 |
    |     11 |     2 |
    |     12 |     1 |
    +--------+-------+
```

For users that have more than 1 jurisdiction, would this be ok to have repeated userdID rows? or would it be better to have extra JurID columns and have them set as null if not used? such as:

```
user_jurisdiction
+--------+-------++--------+-------+
| userID | jurID |  jurID | jurID  |
+--------+-------++--------+-------+
|      6 |     2 |       3|    null|
|     11 |     2 |    null|    null|
|     12 |     1 |    null|    null|
+--------+-------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `user_jurisdiction` table because you have a many-to-many relationship between users and jurisdictions.

So, have multiple rows in `user_jurisdiction` for a single user, one row per jurisdiction:

```
6   2
6   3
11  2
12  1
```

For your example.

Also, you should include an auto-incrementing `UserJurisdictionId` in that table.  It is a good idea for every table to have a primary key.

And, you can remove `user.jurID` from the `user` table.  All information about jurisdictions should be in `user_jurisdictions`.  You would use a `join` to get the jurisdiction information for a particular user.